# Log4j2 isn´t working in JAX-RS servlet project on JBoss 7.4

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, log4j2, jboss7.x

I am working on a JAX-RS servlet project, which is deployed on JBoss (7.4) server, I want to implement Log4j2 (2.20) for application log handling, but when I use the `info` method, it does not show anything in the console or in the `server.log` file of the server.

I added the Log4j2 dependencies to `lib` folder on my project.

```
log4j-api-2.20.0.jar
log4j-core-2.20.0.jar
```

This is the configuration for Log4j2 in `src\main\resources\log4j2.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="LogToFile" fileName="${sys:jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.sematext.blog" level="info" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I excluded the JBoss logging subsystem in the `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This is the class where I'm using it.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ExampleServiceImpl.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/getListData")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Override
    public ExampleResp getListData() {
        LOGGER.info("Inside of getListData method");
        ExampleDAOImpl exampleDAOImpl = new ExampleDAOImpl();
        ExampleResp resp = new ExampleResp();
        resp.setListData(exampleDAOImpl.getData());
        return resp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to try to use a different log manager which writes to the `server.log`. The two log managers could end up writing over the file which could result in missing or jumbled log messages.

There is [log4j2-jboss-logmanager](https://github.com/jboss-logging/log4j2-jboss-logmanager) project which will write log4j2 log messages to the JBoss Log Manager. The module is already present in JBoss EAP 7.4. This means all you should need to do is:

1. Remove the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or at least remove module exclusions
2. Add the `<scope>provided</scope>` to the `org.apache.logging:log4j-api` Maven dependency
3. Remove the `org.apache.logging:log4j-core`

This does not support configuring log4j with a configuration file. It uses the configuration in the logging subsystem for configuration. However, given your configuration this should be fine.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I need to use a config file, because I want to print them in json format from my web application. It could be in another log file to avoid missing or messed up log messages.

Comment: You can print log messages in JSON format with the logging subsystem. If you don't want to do that though, then you need to keep the excludes and NOT write to the server.log.